# Is it possible to search through an entire tuple for an entry without iterating?

Tags: python, arrays, for-loop, tuples, iteration

My program needs to search through a list containing month numbers and values. (January is 1, February is 2 etc...).
If it finds the month integer, I want to append its corresponding value to the avg_tuple array. If it does not find the month integer, I want it to append "N/A" to the output_tuple array, for reporting. Is it possible to search through my list without using the:
{ for i in my_list: }
method?

The purpose of my program is, for example, to take an average of all the values for January. Then report it. Then to take an average of the values for February and January and report. Then March, February and January (and so on as the months continue...). If a month does not have a value for this list, I would like it to report N/A. I have tried the { if x in my_list } method with no success.

Here is my code:

```
my_list = [(2, 181), (2, 183), (3, 376), (4, 205)]
input tuple = my_list

#Function to calculate and report back the average duration for each month
def average_duration(input_tuple):
    output_tuple = []
    average_tuple = []

    for number in range(1,13):
        for i in input_tuple:
            if i[1] == number:
                average_tuple.append(i[3])
        if len(average_tuple)==0:
            output_tuple.append("N/A")
            pass
        else:
            output_tuple.append((sum(average_tuple))/len(average_tuple))

    return output_tuple
```

This is my current output. Each value is for each month. (I am reporting them in a spreadsheet using OpenPyxl):

```
my_list     N/A 182 246.6666667 236.25  236.25  236.25  236.25  236.25  236.25  236.25  236.25  236.25
```

This is my intended output:

```
my_list     N/A,  182,  246.6666667, 236.25,  N/A,  N/A,  N/A,  N/A,  N/A,  N/A,  N/A,  N/A
```

Comment: your indices for `i` have changed (you're using 1 and 3 instead of 0 and 1). Your code now prints all `N/A` for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try taking advantage of a dictionary to keep track of all your months at once, so you don't have to loop through it so many times:

```py
from collections import defaultdict

my_list = [(2, 181), (2, 183), (3, 376), (4, 205)]
input_tuple = my_list

#Function to calculate and report back the average duration for each month
def average_duration(input_tuple):
    months = defaultdict(list)

    output_tuple = []

    for month, value in input_tuple:
        months[month].append(value)

    overall_report = []
    for month in range(12):
        report = months[month + 1]
        if not report:
            output_tuple.append("N/A")
        else:
            overall_report.extend(report)
            output_tuple.append(sum(overall_report)/len(overall_report))

    return output_tuple

print(average_duration(input_tuple))
```

Result:

```py
['N/A', 182.0, 246.66666666666666, 236.25, 'N/A', 'N/A', 'N/A', 'N/A', 'N/A', 'N/A', 'N/A', 'N/A']
```

This is essentially as efficient as you can get from a complexity perspective. The code you've modified to show has a complexity of `O(12 * n)` whereas this is `O(12 + N)`. One isn't terribly more inefficient than the other, but you can't exactly find these average values without looping through your entire array, so you are limited to `O(N)`.

Comment: `for month in range(12):` I think this isn't the range to iterate over (January is 1 in his code). Should be `for month in range(1,13):` ?

Comment: Yup, totallly forgot to do plus one, thanks for that catch

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH! You're the best! I've been stuck on that for two days. Thanks again for all of your help :)